# sql query to get the sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i have table with   filmname    and actors column in sql server 2005

i want the sql query to get all the actors of the   film starred by both  "bradpitt" and "rusellcrowe"

the table design is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
    [actors ] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [filmname] [nchar](10) NULL,

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You need to show us your table schema, and maybe some test data. Do you use any delimiters in the actors column? Are all the actors names stored in a single comun?

Comment: no we dont have any delimiters. each row has a single filname and single actor name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the film where both bradpitt and rusellcrowe (russellcrowe?) exist for that film... which then gives you the actors

```
SELECT
    actors
FROM
    dbo.MyTable M1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
             dbo.MyTable M2
        WHERE
             M2.actors = 'bradpitt' AND M1.filmname. = M2.filmname)
    AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
             dbo.MyTable M3
        WHERE
             M3.actors = 'rusellcrowe' AND M1.filmname. = M3.filmname)
```

Comment: +1 @gbn, thanks for pointing that out. I deleted my answer. The key is in the details. :)